# Break-after: right breaks only once

Tags: html, css, handlebars.js

I have a report generated which shows data for several users, which I would like to print out. So simple so far, however, to save paper I would like to print double sided, but still have reports which are separable after printing.
I have tried to set a  wrapper around the document with style set to `break-after: right` which according to the docs should give me what I want, however, it instead only breaks once (the same as `break-after: page` which means that it only breaks once).
I'm not sure if this is a rendering issue, or if handlebars is suppressing blank pages, but either way, it's causing a problem for the kind of report I would like. I am happy to have "page intentionally blank" mark or something if this can help me with the issue somehow.

```
{{#each users as |user|}}
<main style="break-after: right">
{{!... content}}
</main>
{{/each}}
```